# Как сделать на странице уменьшающееся число напр. Осталось 10 товаров через 1 мин 9 тов

Tags: javascript, html

Например есть товар, а возле него, - Осталось 10 шт. через 10 сек 9 шт. и так довести до 1 шт. чтобы стимулировать покупателя..)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var cp = parseInt(document.querySelector('.count').textContent);
  if(cp > 1){
    document.querySelector('.count').textContent  = cp-1;
  }else{
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="count">10</div>
```

setInterval(function(){}, 1000);

Comment: а как сделать чтобы при обновлении страницы скрипт не обновлялся?

Comment: т.е число уменьшилось до 9 и после обновления страницы тоже было 9

Answer (score 2):

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  num = parseInt($('#text > span').html());
  if(num>0)$('#text > span').html(num-1);else clearInterval(interval);
},1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">осталось <span>10</span> шт</div>
```

1000 в setInterval время в микросекундах, если вам нужно 10 сек пишите 10000

Comment: Не микро, а милли.

Comment: @Qwertiy, верно, перепутал)

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p:before {
  content: "10\a 9\a 8\a 7\a 6\a 5\a 4\a 3\a 2\a 1";
  position: relative;
  animation: top-nine steps(9) 9s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes top-nine {
  from { top:     0; }
  to   { top: -900%; }
}
```

```html
<p>
```